# Unity: how to resolve derived types into IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

i have base class and several derived classes. how can i resolve these derived types by means of Unity into IEnumerable collection? i've tried smth like

```
var myObjectList = (IEnumerable<BaseClass>) UnityContainerFactory.UnityContainer.ResolveAll(typeof(BaseClass));
```

But it raises an invalidCastException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use the generic overload of `ResolveAll`.

```
var myObjectList = UnityContainerFactory.UnityContainer
                                        .ResolveAll<BaseClass>();
```

Alternatively, use `Enumerable.Cast`:

```
var myObjectList = UnityContainerFactory.UnityContainer
                                        .ResolveAll(typeof(BaseClass))
                                        .Cast<BaseClass>();
```

Comment: I've chosen the 2nd variant. there is no more exception, but the container is still empty. i register types in the following way: container.RegisterType<BaseClass, DerivedClass1>();
container.RegisterType<BaseClass, DerivedClass2>();

Comment: edited: i registered unnamed types, that's why container was empty. nevertheless, thnx!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Unity, but assuming you're on .NET 3.5 or higher, you might try using LINQ:

```
var myObjectList = UnityContainerFactory.UnityContainer
                                        .ResolveAll(typeof(BaseClass))
                                        .Cast<BaseClass>();
```

(You may want to call `ToList()` to materialize it into a `List<BaseClass>`.)

Comment: I wrote an extension method for doing casting and converting to list in one call: `public static List<T> ToCastedList<T>(this IEnumerable e)
    {
      return e.Cast<T>().ToList();
    }`